# Can't resolve 'react-router'

Tags: reactjs

I've just started ReactJS and trying my first react app.

I am trying to add a navigation as follows-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  {Link}  from 'react-router';

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
      Hello
      <Link to="/category">Category</Link>
      </div>
      
      );
  } 
}


export default App;
```

But, it says

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router'
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: Its `react-router-dom`

Comment: It also gives the not found error.

Comment: that's because you need to install it. `npm install react-router-dom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the package like this:

```sh
npm install --save react-router
```

---

**Update** Having read the docs, you're also importing the `Link` component from the incorrect package.

You need to install the `react-router-dom` package:

```sh
npm i -S react-router-dom
```

And, you should update you code to the following:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: where should I run this command? in project folder?

Comment: Yes, you need to run this command in the terminal from the root of the project directory

Comment: I ran the command. But still I am getting the error.

Comment: See the official docs of [react router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: Show your `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

replace "react-router" by "react-router-dom".

Comment: Sorry I was a bit slow, you have to run this command in a terminal